# I'm trying to output to a div without appending another container

Tags: jquery

The following code will output the word "click" when I click on the page I want it to output to the div with id of **log**  so far the only way I find I can do this is to output to another container then append that container to "#log" in the example if I replace  ("" + event.type + "") with (event.type) nothing happens.  It seems jQuery requires I write to a container in memory before writing to the page. If I change **$("#log").append to **$("div").append($(""+event.type+""));** the first time I click then "click" is output twice, the second time click is output 4 times, then 8, 16 etc.

the code:

```
<script>
function logEvent (event) {
   $("#log").append($("<div>"+event.type"+"</div>"));
   }
$(document).ready (function () {
   $("html").click (logEvent);
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="log"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What `$(event.type)` is supposed to do? jQuery here, `$('click')`, tries to select the `click` elements on the page, is this what you want? Your _question?_ doesn't make sense.

Comment: The logEvent function simply outputs the event "click" every time the mouse is clicked and it works fine.  My question is simply is there a way to output directly into the div without wrapping the output in another div, or p or any other container.  I suspect there is no other way with jQuery.  It just seems a little "Micky Mouse" to me.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is simply is there a way to output directly into the div without wrapping the output in another div

[Check the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Just change the append line to `$("#log").append(event.type);`

Comment: I know it appears to work but it still brings the wrapper with it.  Try this assign a background colors of red to p and blue to div the text now will always be on a red background in a blue container giving a striped effect.  Anyway it's a small point if you append p into p the background the background colors will match and you have double spaced text, if you append div into div you the background colors match and you have single spacing.  I just thought it would be cleaner if you could just move the text node by itself into the div as you can in plain JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not getting the same output as you, sorry. Here's a JSFiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/S2HAr/)

Comment: Thank you, I get it now you can append plain javascript and it accomplishes what I was trying to do.